# Apache virtual host use a webapp what public at port number

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am using Windows Server 2016 Data center, Apache 2.4, ASP.NET Core 2.2

I build ASP.NET Core project, then I run

```
dotnet foodotcom.dll
```

Stand at local Windows server, I can access web app at

```
http://localhost:5000
```

I want use Apache 2.4 to create a virtual host, map domain `foo.com` to `http://localhost:5000` (My server has static IP). How to do that?

(Seemly something like Apache's `ProxyPass`, but I am not sure)

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

in `httpd.conf` , uncomment these lines

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

and

```
<VirtualHost foo.com:80>
    ProxyPass / "http://localhost:5000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`
add this line

```
103.48.xxx.xxx foo.com
```

In domain DNS administration page,
add record

```
@   A  103.48.xxx.xxx
www A 103.48.xxx.xxx
```

We can go to http://foo.com success.